# Render controller and duplicate the output multiple times

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Say I have a classless form that has an entity field, meaning it makes a database call. Now say I want to render the form with that entity field multiple times across a page, each time with a different action. How would one go about doing that. I made an attempt using a macro but each time the macro ran the form was re-rendered which added an additional database call. My goal is to reduce the number of times I hit the database as retrieving the same information again and again is no good.

How would you go about repeating a form multiple times

Comment: You should create something like instances pool. Best of all would be Singleton class with static methods.